# UIRefreshControl not doing action

Tags: ios, swift

So I have enabled refreshing for the table view in Storyboard and put this code into the viewDidLoad() :

```
refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refresh(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

and this is the refresh function:

```
func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("a")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```

The problem is that when I pull to refresh, it does not print "a"(put this for testing) and it does not end refreshing. Why?

Comment: Do you have refreshing enabled in "Attributes Inspector"? I recreated the problem using UITableViewController and it works.

Comment: Yes, http://imgur.com/a/lVLGv

Comment: The only other way I can think of is your Class in "Custom Class" in Identity Inspector. Is it assigned to the same class where this code is located? Since you're already using Storyboards try connecting your refresh control through IBActions (valueChanged) and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, the class is correct. Where is the refresh control located in the storyboard?

Comment: After enabling it in UITableViewController it should show up under TableView. Follow this [link](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-tips-pull-to-refresh-in-less-than-30-seconds-ef884520f0df#.6y8sn3gko) for a guide.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have added it as an answer, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using Storyboards, try connecting your refresh control through IBActions (valueChanged) and see if it works. Follow this [link](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-tips-pull-to-refresh-in-less-than-30-seconds-ef884520f0df#.hyqu2k58f) for a guide